# disable on settings ios local notifications programmatically titanium studio

Tags: ios, notifications, titanium, localnotification, titanium-studio

Is ti some how possible to disable IOS notifications from inside my app?
I need this because my app has some settings with on/off of notifications, and when the user turns notifications off I wold like to change the phone settings of my app to set the notifications to off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible the disable the app's notification settings programmatically.

You can only redirect the user to the Settings app.